# The webview doesn't show the newest content when using 'webview.reload()' after 'webview.loadUrl()'

Tags: android, html, webview, reload

1. For the first time, invoke the method:

```
webview.loadUrl("https://www.google.com").
```

The page shows the google's content.

2. For the second time, invoke the method :

```
webview.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/").
webview.reload();
```

The page still shows the google's content. But the log shows:

```
webview.getUrl()-> https://stackoverflow.com/
webview.getOriginalUrl-> https://www.google.com
```

I am wondering how it happened and how to make it show the newest content when doesn't change App native code?

(To let h5 page to listen the 'reload' event???)
Thanks!

Comment: what do yo mean by new content? show your proper code for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `webview.reload();` The second snippet should simply be:

```
webview.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");
```

I suspect the what you see is the result of `.loadUrl()` starting to load the page, but `.reload()` interrupting this process and reloading the **current page**.

Comment: You are right! But I can do nothing with the native code because the app is already published. I'm searching another way to solve this problem by edit h5 page code.

Comment: Probably the closest you can get with pure HTML is the `beforeunload` event. See this for example: https://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/page-domcontentloaded-load-beforeunload-unload.html

Comment: I can get the page's unload event by 'window.onbeforeunload' as you mentioned, but how to obtain the true url in a html way after webview executed 'webview.loadUrl()' and 'webview.reload()' together?

Comment: The solution is to fix the app. Anything else is a big hack, if possible at all. The problem is that you're changing to a different page, hence the code in your first page will stop working and be replaced with the new page.

Comment: I have the same idea with you. I'm thinking the way of using 'url redirection'. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, why does the '.reload()' interrupt this process and reload the current page? It confuses me when using '.loadUrl()' and '.reload()' together.

Comment: Most likely, because page load is asynchronous. Hence, while first request is being done (maybe even before that, because I suspect this could be queued) a `.reload()` call is done, interrupting everything.

Answer (score 0):

Use webview.clearCache(true) and  webview.clearHistory() after that call the loading method like  webview.loadUrl(link)

Comment: I can do nothing with the native code because the app is already published. Is there a 'html way' to solve this problem?